# How can I change the color of the plot in each iteration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

The following is a part of my matlab code. As it's shown, I would like to plot 8 curves in one plot. But I want to make each curve with one unique color. I also want to change the legend so that it changes for each `i`.

For instance, for i=1 the legend will be gho-1, for i=2 gho-2 and so on. I want it to be automatic because I will change the `i` sometimes from ex:(i=1:20).

```
for i=1:8
.
.
.
plot(b,r,'b');
legend(['qho-',num2str(i)]);    
hold on
end
```

How can I do this?

Hi again,

I have other question:
if I have the following

```
for i=1:8
.
b1=(1:3,:)
b2=(3:6,:)
figure(1);plot(b1,r,'*');
figure(2);plot(b2,r,'*');

Leg{i} = ['qho-',num2str(i)];    

end
legend(Leg)
```

I got only color legend for the last figure only. not for both..
how can I solve that ?!

Thanks again

Comment: You should ask follow up questions as new questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `hold all` instead of `hold on` and put the legend labels in a cell array

```
hold all
for i=1:8
    .
    .
    .
    plot(b,r);

    Leg{i} = ['qho-',num2str(i)];    

end
legend(Leg)
```

See this question for example: [Sparse matrix plot matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076135/sparse-matrix-plot-matlab/16076451#16076451)

---

**NOTE:**

From **Matlab R2014b onward**, `hold on` has been modified to act like `hold all`, i.e. change the colours of the plots each time one is plotted. [The docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?refresh=true) state that the `hold all` syntax will be removed in future releases.

Comment: `hold all` does limit to the stock 7 colors though, and then loops back through.  If you wanted to define your own color set, you could open your figure and `set(gca,'ColorOrder',myColors)`, where `myColors` is an Nx3 matrix of RGB values.

Comment: Hi again,

I have other question:
if I have the following

for i=1:8
.
b1=(1:3,:)
b2=(3:6,:)
figure(1);plot(b1,r,'*');
figure(2);plot(b2,r,'*');
  
Leg{i} = ['qho-',num2str(i)];    

end
legend(Leg)

I got only color legend for the last figure only. not for both..
how can I solve that ?!

Thanks again

Comment: Have `Leg1{}` and `Leg2{}` separate and make sure you call `legend(Leg1)` before you call `figure(2)`

Comment: Hi, 
that is what I did. but only see different legends and colors in the first figure, and the other one I see one legend only (e.g. gho-1)

Answer (score 7):

How about something like:

```
figure, hold on
N = 8;
h = zeros(N,1);    %# store handle to line graphic objects
clr = lines(N);    %# some colormap
for i=1:N
    %# plot random data
    y = cumsum(randn(100,1));
    h(i) = plot(y, 'Color',clr(i,:));
end
hold off
legend(h, num2str((1:N)','gho-%d'))    %# display legend
```

[image: plot]

Comment: that is great as well. many ways to choose :) :).. thank you very much :)

Comment: thank you! is there any way to do the trick with `subplot`'s in a loop? 2 subplots on 1 figure, with additional plots for both on every iteration, e.g