# Change color for each plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I simply have a loop with a few functions that I want to plot with different colors. Should it not just be something like this:

```
 colors = 'rgbm';
 i=0;
 for p=.1:.1:.6;   
    k = ezplot(subs(J,q,p),[0,3]);        
    set(k, 'Color', colors(i));
    i = i+1;
 end
```

This is more preudo-code which does not work. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing? What is it doing versus what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin with `i=1`, not 0.

And add `hold on`at the beginnig, otherwise you only see the last plot

Comment: And if you use `hold all` instead of hold on then you don't even need the `set(...` line, the colours will change automatically.

Comment: You can also use one of the following File Exchange submissions to get more colours:

 - http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors
 - http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42673-beautiful-and-distinguishable-line-colors-+-colormap

Comment: @Dan Hey, that's a good one!

Comment: @Dan: Nice, but then we don't know which color belongs to which plot, rigth?

Comment: @tw-S well you can add a legend with 1 line of code... also they go in order. But ya, if you want full control then no.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks! How do you generate a legend in the loop above (see original post)? The line text in the legend should just be the parameter value of p (i.e., .1,.2,.3,...).

Comment: @tw-S http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236421/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-plot-in-each-iteration-in-matlab/16236580#16236580

Comment: @tw-S if this answer has been helpful to you (which I'm assuming it has since you've accepted it), you should also consider giving it an upvote by clicking on the upward pointing arrow just to the left of the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to plot with different colours, you can create and use a so called colormap, e.g. like this:

```
colors=lines(12);
```

and later on:

```
colors(index)
```

there are other maps like "jet":

[Mathworks-Documentation for colormap](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)